# JavaScript GetElementById is Null but Element Has a Value

Tags: javascript, html, dom, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I'm trying to pass a value from JavaScript to HTML for a Chrome extension. I keep getting an error that the element being referenced is null.

**popup.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="popup.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <h3>Output</h3>
        <br>
        <output id="outputKey">Output goes here</output>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**popup.js**

```
chrome.storage.sync.get("key", function (value) {
    console.log("Output key value: " + value["key"]);
    console.log("Popup output key value: " + document.getElementById("outputKey"));
    //Set document.getElementById("outputKey") to value["key"]
  });
```

The result is that they key value retrieved from storage is valid and is logged to the console correctly when using `console.log("Output key value: " + value["key"]);`. I would like to set this value to the `output` element's value to display it on `popup.html`. I am getting an error that says `document.getElementById("outputKey")` is null.

I was wondering if this is because the extension's page is only displayed when the extension button is clicked in the browser. I tried adding the following with no luck.

**popup.js**

```
...
window.onload = function () {
    chrome.storage.sync.get("key", function (value) {
    console.log("New key value: " + value["key"]);
    document.getElementById("outputKey") = value["key"];
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Your code is running before the DOM is fully loaded. Instead of `onload` execute your code after the the DOM is fully loaded with [`DOMContentLoaded`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded). This will ensure that the element is in the DOM when you are referencing/using that.

**Please Note:** You also have to use the property of the element like `textContent`, `innerText`, `value` etc. to set the value.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  chrome.storage.sync.get("key", function (value) {
    console.log("New key value: " + value["key"]);
    document.getElementById("outputKey").value = value["key"];
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are trying to access the elements before the DOM loads the elements in the HTML.
Two ways you can tackle this.

1. When you define your script on the "head", add the 'defer' attribute  `<script defer src="script.js"></script>`  OR
2. You may include your script file in the HTML just before the end of the "body" section.

Answer (score -2):

use below code:

```
document.getElementById("outputKey").value = value["key"];
```